# How can I check the total played time of a character?

Tags: diablo-iii

I want to know where or how I can see how long I have played, so far, a certain character. I tried "/played", like in World of Warcraft, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to find out how long I've played in *Diablo III*?

Comment: WoW /played = Forever

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To find out how long you've played a certain character, when you're on the character selection screen, select a given character. It says on the right how long you've played them:

[image: image for time played of character]

You can also find out how long you've played a class. When you're on the screen just after the character selection screen (the one from which you start a game, change quest, etc), press P to bring up your profile.

You'll see a screen that looks like this:

[image: image for time played of class]

Hover over the class to bring up a tooltip for how long you've played it.

Comment: It was Shift-P for me, but it's the first icon in the lower right anyways. :)